# Is the character played by Andy García in Stand and Deliver based on a real person?

Tags: character, casting, stand-and-deliver

In the movie [Stand and Deliver (1988)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand_and_Deliver) Andy Garcia plays Ramirez, one of the two ETS officials who start an investigation into the alleged cheating of the Hispanic students in their AP Calculus exam. It is apparent that the director and producers are trying to balance the race factor out by casting a Hispanic actor as a member of the accusing party. I think one defining line is the character Ramirez shouting: "No one has the right to accuse me of racism!"

But since this movie is based on a true story. I wonder if there was a Latin American who worked for ETS and was involved in ETS' investigation of this case. Are there records of any ETS officials involved or is that part totally fictitious?

Comment: Given some of the other liberties taken in the story (e.g., it was four years after Escalante began teaching at Garfield that he taught his first Calculus class and not to the students depicted as having trouble with basic math), I would imagine that it is fictitious. Jay Mathews's book, *Escalante: The Best Teacher in America* is a good source for an accurate account of Escalante's teaching career.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, he's a real person. I worked with him in Mono County; he was the superintendent of the MHS school district for a few years. His real name was Frank Ramero. I had him talk to my classes about it many years ago.

Comment: Wow, I am totally blown away by this answer. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! This would be an excellent answer *if* you could provide evidence of this.

Comment: Zero hits doing a search for this person's name associated with the movie.